# What is double plus mark in gitk?

Tags: git, diff, patch

`git diff HEAD HEAD^2` shows a single `+`, but gitk shows 2, as in the following figure. I wonder why.

```
 +  int k = 0;
 +  for(; j < i; ++i){
 +    for (k = 0; k < 1000; ++k){
++      if(groupids[k] ==0){
++        break;
++      }
 +      if(groupids[k] == groupid[j]){
 +          return 1;
```

Comment: [don't put code in image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Just copy and paste here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the commit is a merge, and that line is a new line not appearing in either original commits

> A `-` character in the column N means that the line appears in fileN but it does not appear in the result. A `+` character in the column N means that the line appears in the result, and fileN does not have that line (in other words, the line was added, from the point of view of that parent).
>
> In the above example output, the function signature was changed from both files (hence two `-` removals from both file1 and file2, plus `++` to mean one line that was added does not appear in either file1 or file2). Also eight other lines are the same from file1 but do not appear in file2 (hence prefixed with +).
>
> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format

So put it simply, a diff of a line in a merge commit is prepended by 2 characters. If the line is the same in both commits, it's 2 spaces. If the line is from either of the commit then a single `+` will be shown in that commit's column. If the line is remove from some commit then `-` is shown in that commit's column. And if the line is new then it's `++`. You can see the example in the document above:

```
- static void describe(char *arg)
 -static void describe(struct commit *cmit, int last_one)
++static void describe(char *arg, int last_one)
  {
 +  unsigned char sha1[20];
 +  struct commit *cmit;
    struct commit_list *list;
    static int initialized = 0;
    struct commit_name *n;
```

The line `static void describe(char *arg, int last_one)` above is different from both parent commits, so the original lines were marked with `-` to indicate that those are not available in the output file, then `++` is used to mark the updated line

Comment: `git diff` shows one +, but gitk shows two +. And I just checked, it is not a merge commit. Just a commit